# Retaining button visible when onClick function activated

Tags: javascript

Hi I have something similar.
when I click `MESSAGE1` button the the text `Hello World` appears and the button disappears.
When the button is clicked how do I retain the button alongside the text?

```
<button onclick="document.write('<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>');">MESSAGE 1</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Instead of using document.write](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice), you can create a html element place holder and then set its content

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('message').innerHTML = '<?php echo 'Hello World'; ?>';">MESSAGE 1</button>
<span id="message"></span>
```

The button is remove because, [from this doc](http://javascript.crockford.com/script.html)

> document.write is recklessly dependent on timing. If document.write is
>   called before the onload event, it appends or inserts text into the
>   page. If it is called after onload, it completely replaces the page,
>   destroying what came before.